# Moving backwards in a FORWARD for loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I 'm not sure how to explain this and I cannot find an answer anywhere. I have a for loop that loops through lines that are represented through strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.Length; i++)
{

    jumpPoint:
        Debug.Log("Jumped");

    string[] words = dataLines[i].Split();
    .
    .               
    . "words[] manipulation and reading"
    .
    .
}
```

I have no problems with any of my data processing or things that happen in the loop.
But I have an instance where i need to go to a previous `dataLine[]` and continue from that point (also re-runs code that has already been run since that point).

What I am doing essentially boils down to

```
i = ?; //arbitrary number for the situation that is definitely not out of bounds for the loop
goto jumpPoint;
```

Ive also tried without the jump point also just letting the loop cycle to the next after resetting the for loop index.

I know it's not an issue with the jump point as its used for unrelated things and the jump works fine. Also worth mentioning, that in those instances, I am increasing the `i` index so the for loop prematurely advances and that works perfect.

So why can I not go backwards in the loop? Is that just something that is not possible?

Comment: This sounds like a poor design from the get go. What you are describing is inviting an infinite loop to happen. In other words, if you need to loop back up to a lower index, then it sounds like you need a different kind of loop like possibly a `while` loop. It is difficult to say without knowing “what” you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnG I should have clarified. I'm writing a simple pseudo language for a game I am making. And I want the possibility of an infinite loop to happen if the user writes a program that will cause that. This code lives in its own little area with checks so that infinite running code (which I have already implemented in a different style) can be closed while maintaining the overall program. The need for my question is for a "goto" type statement in the pseudo-language.

Comment: If that is something infeasible or just not going to work Ill scrap that part of it as its not totally necessary in the grand scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is stopping you from going backwards in the loop.  You are in control of your code logic, so all you have to do is when your "jumpPoint" condition is met, just change the iterator `i` back to the previous value that you desire.

For example: Let's say I want to jump back and re-run something because it had the word "jump" in it.

```
Console.WriteLine("App started.");
List<string> dataLines = new List<string>() { "this is a phrase", "This is another but with jump in it", "this is the last" };
bool alreadyJumped = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Currently Iterating: {i}");
    string[] words = dataLines[i].Split();
    Console.WriteLine($"Do some with this data: {dataLines[i]}");
    if (words.Contains("jump") && !alreadyJumped)
    {
        alreadyJumped = true;

        // Reset the i value so that the next iteration will run again.
        i = i - 1;
    }
    else if (alreadyJumped)
    {
        // Once 
        alreadyJumped = false;
    }

}
Console.WriteLine("App done.");
```

This will produce this output:

```
App started.
Currently Iterating: 0
Do some with this data: this is a phrase
Currently Iterating: 1
Do some with this data: This is another but with jump in it
Currently Iterating: 1
Do some with this data: This is another but with jump in it
Currently Iterating: 2
Do some with this data: this is the last
App done.
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. When attempting in the fashion I showed above or other ways similar to your comment, the program crashes, I am just not understanding why. I have no debug output or anything to go off of, making me think this just isn't possible, but I am not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a big void into what you are doing in your code when you "jump" that we can't see or understand, without you providing us a minimal reproducible sample.  Not sure what your issue is, but the code I provided above was compiled and ran to produce the output I posted, so I know that it's possible to jump around where ever I want in the for loop.

Comment: Yea I think I have something going on down the line causing an issue that is only arising when trying to do this. This file is 1000's of lines, so I will scour until I figure it out, I appreciate the help. It made me realize it's likely something else.

Comment: Yep, I agree. Sounds like something else. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand but you mean something like this:

```
        var i = 0;
        var startRun = true;

        while (true)
        {
            if (!startRun && i == dataLines.Length - 1)
                return;

            if (startRun)
                startRun = false;

            /* do stuff */

            if (needToJump)
            {
                clearLogicOrWhatever();
                i = whereYouNeedToJump;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
```

Of course you will need more validation if going out of index, if step exists or in range and other stuff, this is just like a proof of concept / pseudo.